# Setting default skin for individual pages in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm able to set the default skin for all pages in mediawiki by using $wgDefaultSkin in LocalSettings.php.  However, what I would like to do is to change the skin for particular individual pages.

For example, I would like to set the skin for specific individual pages to be "chick", while leaving the default skin for all other pages as "vector".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, this isn't possible. MediaWiki supports to set a default skin for all pages. Additionally, any user can change the skin for all pages in the preferences. Having different pages with different skins sounds very confusing for the user, btw.

However, you could use the [SkinPerPage extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SkinPerPage) to achieve this in a on-wiki configurable way; or the [SkinPerNamespace extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SkinPerNamespace), which does the same, but per namespace (like the name says ;)). Furthermore, with some developing time you can achieve this in a wiki-sysadmin (using the LocalSettings.php settings) configurable way (so your users can't change the skin preference using a parser function). E.g. you could [create an extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions), which uses the [`RequestContextCreateSkin` hook](http://mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/RequestContextCreateSkin), to change the skin based on the given Title. E.g.:

```
<?php
/**
 * RequestContextCreateSkin handler. Used to change the skin, based on the given title.
 *
 * @param IContextSource $context The context, in which this hook was called.
 * @param Skin|null|string $skin The Skin object or the skin name, if a skin was
 *  created already, null if not.
 */
public static function onRequestContextCreateSkin( $context, &$skin ) {
    // get the Config object of your extension to get the configuration we need
    $config = ConfigFactory::getDefaultInstance()->makeConfig( 'your-extension-config' );
    // that's the Title object of the request, from which this hook was called, mostly the Title
    // of the page requested by the user. getPrefixedText() returns the full text of the title, including
    // the namespace but without the fragment hash (e.g. Category:TestTitle)
    $title = $context->getTitle()->getPrefixedText();

    // get the configuration variable $wgFakeExtensionSkinTitleMap, which should be an array map of
    // titles to skin names in the following format:
    // array(
    //    'TestTitle' => 'chick',
    //    'TestTitle2' => 'monobook',
    // );
    $skinTitleMap = $config->get( 'FakeExtensionSkinTitleMap' );
    if ( !is_array( $skinTitleMap ) ) {
        // if the map isn't an array, throw an exception. You could also just log a debug message or do anything else,
        // for this example the exception is good enough
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            '$wgFakeExtensionSkinTitleMap needs to be an array, ' . gettype( $skinTitleMap ) . ' given.' );
    }

    // check, if the current title is configured in our map, which would indicate, that we use our own skin for it
    if ( isset( $skinTitleMap[$title] ) ) {
        // set the skin. You could handle the skin object creation here, too, but if you return a string, the caller
        // of the RequestContextCreateSkin will handle the creation. Probably it's wise to run Skin::normalizeKey()
        // to be sure, that the skin name can be loaded, see the docs for it:
        // https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classSkin.html#af36919e77cfd51eb35767eb311155077
        $skin = $skinTitleMap[$title];
    }
}
```

I hope that the comments explains the code as much as you need to understand it :)

However, like I said earlier: You should think about the impact of such a change. It could be really confusing for the user to get a different page appearance for different titles he opens. It's probably more wise to have a consistent skin for every page (there's a reason why the MediaWiki devs haven't implemented such a function, yet ;)).